# Cannot install Olsrr

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install Olsrr, but only get the following error message (see below). 
I have tried to update "update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE), but it still does not work.

How can I resolve this?

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'ellipsis' ...
** package 'ellipsis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ellipsis'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ellipsis'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'ellipsis' had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependency 'ellipsis' is not available for package 'vctrs'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/vctrs'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'vctrs' had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependency 'vctrs' is not available for package 'pillar'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'pillar' had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependencies 'ellipsis', 'pillar', 'vctrs' are not available for package 'tibble'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/tibble'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'tibble' had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

Comment: In the past, I've seen updating or (re)installing XCode to be a way to address this.

Comment: I am quite new to R, what does re-installing the Xcode imply?

Comment: It is not R, it is macos. I don't have it, I just recall others claiming that problems similar to this ("invalid active developer path") were resolved when XCode with either installed, updated, or reinstalled, depending on several factors. Sorry, not a lot to offer, but try removing "R" from your search on how to update/fix xcode issues.